# OptaPlanner Project Job Scheduling sample data explanation

Tags: optaplanner

could someone please explain me how to model my own data for Project Job Scheduling problem in OptaPlanner?
I see that there are xml files, txt files and a lot of .mm files (j1010_1.mm) and I don't see any way how to model my own input.

What do these numbers in sample A_1.txt mean?

2
0
10
j10.mm/j1011_7.mm
4
19
j10.mm/j1060_2.mm
4
16  -1  -1  -1

I guess it's

2 - number of projects
0 - release date
10 - critical path duration
and for the rest I have no idea.

j10.mm/j1011_7.mm
4 
19
j10.mm/j1060_2.mm
4
16  -1  -1  -1

I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Maybe you can find anything useful in the [ProjectJobSchedulingImporter](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/persistence/ProjectJobSchedulingImporter.java)?

Comment: @Abby ok thanks, I'm gonna check it. It's so user unfriendly though.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the docs have a reference to the challenge that specced out the entire input files:
  https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#projectJobScheduling

which links to
  http://gent.cs.kuleuven.be/mista2013challenge/

But unfortunately, it looks like that challenge website is offline right now... although it's still in google, so the offline might be temporarily.

Comment: We (= OptaPlanner team) should really invest some time in creating a better "job shop scheduling" example out of the box. But first we need a maintenance scheduling example. All in good time...

Comment: Quite pity that it's not included within the docs. I would be happier for input files in a format like in Task assigning. It's a lot of work to do as well but at least that xml file is quite nice and you can write it on your own :) .. I mean, thanks for your hint, I'll try to find something useful but I think I'm not gonna use this solution because of complexity of its input files, especially those .mm whatever it is.